# want to sort array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array in javascript like this:

```
   var array=[-2,+4,-1,+3,+6,0,+1,-5,+2,-3,+5,-4,-6]
```

now I want to sort this array to [-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,+1,+2,+3,+4,+5,+6] 
     can anyone help me please?

Comment: It doesn't look like string... `array.sort(function(a, b){ return a-b; })`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: That's not a string array. Those are numbers.

Comment: [Google is your friend](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=javascript%20sort%20array%20of%20numbers)

Comment: @SterlingArcher I thought he was mine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sorts an array in reverse

```
var array=[-2,+4,-1,+3,+6,0,+1,-5,+2,-3,+5,-4,-6]
console.log(array.sort(function(a, b){ return a-b; }))
```